# What is the meaning of the phrase 「歯のたつ相手」?

Tags: manga, phrases

It is a situation that a boy who wanted to retaliate to another one but was prevented by an officer.

The first boy: はなせっ　あのやろうとケリをつけるんだ　こないだの借りをたたきかえしてやるんだっ

The officer (said to the first boy): この問題児めおまえに**歯のたつ相手**か！

In my opinion, the officer would ask something about how the first boy retaliate to the another one by using his teeth. However, I don't see any transitive verb to use with 'his teeth'. Is it possible that the phrase contains figurative meaning?

Comment: `お前に歯の立つ相手か！` -> You could rephrase it 「お前に[敵]{かな}う相手か！」

Comment: 歯が立たない⇒can't bite⇒can't beat.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it has to do with [歯が立たない](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%AD%AF%E3%81%8C%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-597790).

> ②自分の力が弱くて，対抗することや理解することができない。

But in the manga it is said in the affirmative + か, probably meaning:

"You think you're stronger than him??!" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

- おまえに歯の立つ相手か！
- Do you think you stand a chance?  -- (a fighting chance, literally)

> 鳴門秘帖　https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=ng3nBgAAQBAJ
>
> 吉川英治 -- 不意に名を指されたいぶかしさに、思わずそこから振りかえると、「そちに歯の立つ相手ではない。必ずとも追ってはならぬ」「や?・・・・・・もし」と銀五郎、戻ってくるなり虚無僧の足もとへ片膝片手をつきながら、「まず何よりは、今のお礼から申し上げなくっちゃなり ...

- 「そちに歯の立つ相手ではない。必ずとも追ってはならぬ」
- [He's no match for you.  Do not pursue.]

おまえに歯の立つ相手か！ -- this か is actually negative. (rhetorical question) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34861/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8B/ 
>   ２.  反語の意を表す。「いいかげんな意見にどうして賛成できよう―」